# Creating Aeronautical maps covering entire Colombo Flight Information Region (FIR)?

Tags: coordinate-system, ais, sri-lanka

ICAO need Aeronautical maps in WGS84 Coordinate System but in ArcGIS length can't be given or measure as it's a GCS.

In Sri Lanka we have SLD99(EPSG5233), Kandawala/Sri Lanka Grid(EPSG5234) and UTM44(EPSG32644) PCSs.

What PCS or PCSs should be used to create Aeronautical maps (Aerodrome, Approach and En-route) for the whole Colombo FIR?

Comment: I'm quite sure ArcGIS *can* report geodetic distance from data in WGS84 coordsys. There are many potential projections available, the choice of which is both *broad* and *opinion-based*.